# Observable result check if not empty

Tags: java, android, observable, system.reactive

Please help me
I have such pattern, how can I check if `id` is empty and if it is, return from the function.

```
Observable<String> observable.flatMap(id -> {return ....})   // something like id.isEmpty return;
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(id -> {.....});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "return from the function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [forEachWhile](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#forEachWhile-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-):

```
observable.forEachWhile(item->!item.isEmpty()).flatMap(id -> {...}) ...
```